# Javascript - can console.log an object inside a function but when returned it is comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a function to geocode a zipcode, and return the lat and lng to an object, and then return this object. I am then trying to assign the value of this geocode function to a variable to create an object.

When I console log the object created in this function, I get an object returned in my terminal as expected:

```
const geo = (zip) => {
    geocoder.geocode(zip, function(err, data) {
                let latLng = {};
                latLng.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                latLng.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                console.log(latLng); // Returns Object As Expected    
        });        
};
```

But when I instead replace the `console.log(latLng)` with `return latLng` I get an undefined value when assigning this function to a variable like so:

```
let newObj = geo(zip);
console.log(newObj) // Returns Undefined
```

I am confused because the initial `console.log` does show an object is being made in the geocode function, but when I use `return` it is coming back as `undefined`. I think it is an issue with how I am assigning it to a variable. I am misunderstanding something without doubt.

Comment: What is `geocoder`? What does `geocode` return (if anything)?

Comment: Your object letlang is declare using let, so moment you move out of callback function, letlang will be out of scope (block level scope) and you will get undefined. so move its scope out of callback function.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar that's a terrible idea

Comment: @Phil how my idea is terrible? Kindly guide me. :)

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar that will take latLng out of the scope of the callback function and then latLng will just be an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing async (via callbacks with sync), you could use promises to simplify this

```
const geo = (zip) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       geocoder.geocode(zip, (err, data) => {
            let latLng = {};
            latLng.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            latLng.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            resolve(latLng);  
       });
    })         
};
```

you can utilise the function then like

```
geo(zip).then(latLng => {
  console.log(latLng) // or whatever
})
```

Comment: I wouldn't ignore `err`. Why not add `if (err) return reject(err)`?

Comment: @Phil i wouldn't also not ignore, `err`, i was just showing him how he can get it done (more of as a pseudo code), and not a complete solution

Comment: @maison.m as @Phil suggested, you will have to handle `err` by rejecting, the promise, and you can also ideally use `await` to consume the function as well

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks for the explanation, that helped me immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a return statement. Avoid the arrow in this case and just use a normal function. .geocode() method return value is not assigned in any way. You need to keep throwing the value back to its caller.

```
const geo = function(zip) {
        return geocoder.geocode(zip, function(err, data) {
                let latLng = {};
                latLng.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                latLng.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng; 

                console.log(latLng); // Returns Object As Expected    
                return latLng;
        });       

};
```

Comment: This won't make any difference. You're just adding a return value to the `geocode` callback which isn't assigned anywhere.

Comment: I  realised that. Edited. @Phil

Comment: Assuming it's Google's geocoder, `geocode` doesn't return anything ~ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#Geocoder

Comment: Then he must try to use a global variable in order to access the value

Comment: There are much better options than that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022448/283366

Answer (score -1):

You can try async-await because geocode method is asynchronous.
Reference: [How to make this method asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151988/how-to-make-this-method-asynchronous)